# How to generate dynamic batch file and execute it using Azure data factory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

We are currently migrating our solution from SSIS to Azure Data factory. In our existing solution (in SSIS) we are using a script task to dynamically generate a batch file with few parameters in stored in our metadata database. There are multiple batch files which needs to be executed in sequence, we are using for each loop to execute these dynamically generated batch files.

The batch file name which is generated as the output for the script task is then used by the execute process task- which executes this batch command. In case of SSIS , we can parameterize the execute process task to execute the batch file present in the variable name.

We would like to migrate this process to ADF, can you please let us know what tasks should we use to achieve this functionality.

Comment: As a trial to consolidate, you need to 1. input parameters 2. interact with metadata database 3. control the sequence of the interactions? Am I understanding your tasks correctly?

Comment: I need to do the below tasks:

1. Get the metadata information from the Control Database, I can use lookup for this.
2. Execute a powershell command which generates the batch file(and executes it as well) in an Azure VM shared path with the parameters obtained from the 1st step.

Comment: I am trying to map some potential alternatives to batch file in ADF. For a brief looking, your interaction with control database through batch can be replaced by [dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview). For the sequenced execution of the batch, you can control them in a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers).